# Text gets cut off in accessoryCircular lock screen widget

Tags: swiftui, lockscreen, widgetkit, lockscreenwidget

I am working on an `accessoryCircular` (lock screen) widget that shows 2 values; a formatted $$ value and a 3-letter word.

The $$ value can be anything (e.g., $0 or $200K or 400M or 500B). I am formatting dollar values with a KMB if they exceed $1,000. The value needs to fit 1 line.

The problem I am facing is that for large $$ values, the right side gets cut off. If you look at the images, the `M` gets cut off from the `$10.51M`.

How can I best ensure fitting the value within the visible boundaries of an accessoryCircular's view?

Currently, I am using the following code, but it doesn't do the trick:

```
var entry: Provider.Entry
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(entry.abc)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                Text("ABC")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            }
        }
```

I have been experimenting with adjusting font size dynamically, but I haven't found a good way.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lock screen widgets are limited to just a few system fonts.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-lock-screen-widgets-and-watch-complications#Use-system-font-styles):

> ## Use system font styles
>
> Lock Screen widgets and watch complications appear adjacent to other widgets or complications, making a consistent look for your content that fits in well with the other elements a priority. To achieve a consistent look for your widgets and complications, use system fonts, default font parameters, and the following font styles:
>
> - `Font.TextStyle.headline`
> - `Font.TextStyle.title`
> - `Font.TextStyle.body`
> - `Font.TextStyle.caption`

To make your text fit the area, you are doing well with `.minimumScaleFactor`, try a lower `factor`, for example: `0.1`.

Alternatively, try shortening your text.